# How to deserialize blaze persistence entity view from JSON programatically?

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, blaze-persistence

Is there a way to programatically deserialize JSON to blaze-persistence entity view?
When I'm using standard jackson object mapper, and trying to do

`mapper.readValue(serializedJSON, EntityViewImpl.class);`

where serializedJSON is string representation (serialized from the same class of entity view), and EntityViewImpl.class is code-generated implementation of entity view interface, I'm getting an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of  (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate or property based Creator)
> at [Source: (String) "{JSON representation of EntityView}"; line: 1, column: 2]
> .

Same JSON correctly deserializes into entity that was basis for used entity view.

I noticed that there is a custom deserialization functionality as part of the blaze-persistance, although was not able to find any related documentation.

So any answer, eighther with standard jackson mapper or with custom blaze-persistence functionality would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jackson integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#usage-5) which allows you to deserialize creatable/updatable entity views. There are integrations for [JAX-RS](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#jaxrs-integration) and Spring [WebMvc](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-webmvc-integration)/[WebFlux](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-webflux-integration) and even [GraphQL](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#graphql-integration) though, so chances are, you don't have to do this plumbing yourself. If you share some more details like the entity view and the are where you want to do deserialization, I can give you a more extensive answer.